# SilverStripe 4: Where is the database configuration?

Tags: php, database, config, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've been reading the doc's on this but totally confused. My mysite/_config.php file is empty after install. Where do I find the database settings for the site such as username, database name and password?

Doc's page here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/changelogs/4.0.0/#env

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define them in a `.env` file, see the `.env.example` file which comes with the installer for a template.

The example (from the link you posted):

```
## Environment {#environment}
SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="admin"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password"
SS_BASE_URL="http://localhost/"

## Database {#database}
SS_DATABASE_CHOOSE_NAME="true"
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLDatabase"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=""
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="127.0.0.1"
```

Note that `SS_DATABASE_CHOOSE_NAME` will determine a DB name automatically for you and create it. If you want to use a specific DB name you can ignore this line and set `SS_DATABASE_NAME` instead.